# PowerBI - Declining Trend Over Time

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, measure, burndowncharts

I'm working on a PowerBI Dashboard where I have a set number of values (Training Session -3084 Sessions) an assigned date of 2/15/20 and a due date of 3/28/20.

I'm trying to show a trend over time of the declining incompletions as we approach our goal and I'm now stuck.

I've created Date Range Table that lists each date between the Assigned Date and Finish as well as a custom columns that counts the corresponding completions for each date but I'm not sure how to tally up the incompletions and show the decline over time.

Columns: Session (Course Name), Status (Completion Status), Due Date (Date Session is Due) [PowerBI Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI53V.jpg)

[Measure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW647.jpg)

[Updated Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IIEY.jpg)

[Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEmtc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the following measure. Put the Date column of the Date Range table on the axis of your chart and this measure as the value. This measure follows the following [DAX pattern](https://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/) with the addition of subtracting the cumulative completions from the total session count.

```
Remaining Incompletions Count = 
CALCULATE(
 COUNTROWS(Data),
 ALL(Data),
 ALL('Date Range')
)
- CALCULATE(
 SUM('Date Range'[Completions by Date]),
 FILTER(
  ALL('Date Range'[Date]), 
  'Date Range'[Date] <= MAX('Date Range'[Date])
 )
)
```

Comment: Hey Greg, thanks so much for the response. The measure worked but the result worked opposite of expected. It gives the running count of completions instead of subtracting  completions from the total sessions. I'm not sure what I should change.

Comment: @MM18 can you share a screenshot of the relationships between tables? If you comment all but the COUNTROWS(Sessions) lime what does it show?

Comment: I actually don't have a table named Sessions, so i used my table "Data" instead. Should I create another table named Session ?  I've added the relationship screenshot

Comment: @MM18 I updated the answer. Applying ALL to both tables is a bit heavy handed since some filters on the table (like session type) you may not want to remove. But without a full picture of your data model this should at least work and solve the problem

Comment: Not quite, i had to do a few more steps to get the result i was lookin for but you helped me get in the direction that I needed to be.